# load Date From DB to view with matching date in Full Calendar

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar

I have date,project Id,task ID and workedHours in my table(SQL). I need to bind this to my timesheet view. I use full calendar here in weekly view. I bind the Projects and Tasks as follows :

```
 <tr style="background-color:#ded9d9;color:#000">
                    <td colspan="9">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Project_Name)                        
                    </td>

                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td style="padding-left:6%; width:22%;">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Task_Name)
                    </td>
                    <td style=" width:7%;">
                        <input id="Day1" name="Day1" type="text" value=@item.Hrs_Worked style="width:70%;" />
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:6%;">
                        <input id="Day2" name="Day2" type="text" value="" style="width:80%;" />
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:6%;">
                        <input id="Day3" name="Day3" type="text" value="" style="width:80%;" />
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:6%;">
                        <input id="Day4" name="Day4" type="text" value="" style="width:80%;" />
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:6%;">
                        <input id="Day5 @i" name="Day5" type="text" value="" style="width:80%;" />
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:6%;">
                        <input id="Day6" name="Day6" type="text" value="" style="width:80%;" />
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:6%;">
                        <input id="Day7" name="Day7" type="text" value="" style="width:80%;" />
                    </td>
```

I have textboxes dynamically loaded based on number of projects here. Now i listed the available projects here successfully. But I need to bind Worked hrs in these Textboxes dynamically matching with date from full calendar. I display only weekly calendar here so totally seven textboxes here i used
In attached image i shown my current status..
Can anyone help me to over come this..

[image: Here WorkedHoures for each projects will show in textboxes dynamically]

Comment: Cannot find your image?

Comment: sorry I am not able to attach image here as i have low reputations I use this for Full Calendar Header here.  var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar(
                {
                    header: {
                        left: 'prev',
                        center: 'title',
                        right: 'next'
                    }, defaultView: 'basicWeek',  });  });

Comment: upload it in any public server like image stack and give the link

Comment: Hi I upload my image here http://postimg.org/image/olqqa78kj/